# Get current CMS page id in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to retrieve the current CMS page id in Magento2. Below is the code I used for Magento1.x which obviously doesnt work anymore. But I can not get my head around how to do this for Magento2.

```
if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms') {
    $_pageId = Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/page')->getPage()->getPageId();
}
```

Using the registry as shown below wont work.

```
 $this->_coreRegistry->registry('cms_page')->getId()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I found out after digging around in the CMS helper function.

```
protected $_page;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page,
    ...
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    ...
    $this->_page = $page;
    ...
}

if ($this->_page->getId()) {
    $pageId = $this->_page->getId();
}
```

Comment: This code is an example on how to include the functionality in a block or helper class. It is not to be copied  1 on 1. Check out the CMS helper for more context at \vendor\magento\module-cms\Helper\Page.php

Comment: Is this really the right way to achieve this? It does seem kind of weird to use DI to inject an object that holds a state.

Comment: @Solide How Can I get page information per store view I've tried `$this->_pageFactory->create()->setStoreId(1)->load($cmsId)` ?

Answer (score 14):

**With ObjectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cmsPage = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');

echo $cmsPage->getIdentifier(); //Get Current CMS Page Identifier
echo $cmsPage->getId(); //Get Current CMS Page ID
```

**With Factory Method**

```
protected $_cmsPage;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $cmsPage,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_cmsPage = $cmsPage;
    ...
}

echo $this->_cmsPage->getIdentifier(); //Get Current CMS Page Identifier
echo $this->_cmsPage->getId(); //Get Current CMS Page ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution. This will help you to identify the current CMS page.

```
<?php
    $objectManagerCms = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cmsPage = $objectManagerCms->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');
    echo $cmsPage->getIdentifier();
    echo $cmsPage->getId();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you in same layout `cms_page_view`

> $pageId= $this->getLayout()->getBlock("cms_page")->getPage()->getId();