# How can I restrict SPECIFIC CMS pages from being seen by non logged in customers?

Tags: magento2, redirect, cms

I found solutions for redirecting non logged in users to the login page for all CMS pages, but I only want to restrict a few CMS pages. How can I specify which pages to restrict?

My code right now:

```
...\etc\frontend\events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view">
        <observer name="add_login_checker" instance="<vendor>\<plugin>\Observer\RestrictCmsPage"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

```
...\observer\RestrictCmsPage.php

<?php

namespace <vendor>\<plugin>\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RestrictCmsPage implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->authenticate()) {
            $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            if (!$this->customerSession->getBeforeUrl()) {
                $this->customerSession->setBeforeUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
            }
        }
        return  $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could create an array of CMS page IDs that require login, use logic in your observer to check the current CMS page id against this array.

Answer (score 0):

Reference url

> [Get current CMS page id in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98649/get-current-cms-page-id-in-magento2#answer-151611)

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<plugin>\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RestrictCmsPage implements ObserverInterface
{
    
    protected $_actionFlag;
    
    protected $_cmsPage;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $cmsPage,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->_cmsPage = $cmsPage;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if($this->_cmsPage->getIdentifier() == "your_identifier_name"){
            if (!$this->customerSession->authenticate()) {
                $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                if (!$this->customerSession->getBeforeUrl()) {
                    $this->customerSession->setBeforeUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
                }
            }
        }
        return  $this;
    }
}
```